# Xpath implementation in Google Sheets

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, xquery

Xpath newbie question, so forgive me if this seems straight forward, but I really have looked everywhere for the answer!

I'm trying to build a process for extracting all my playlists from Spotify and making it universal, allowing migration across various platforms. I will gladly share once completed as I know many people would find this useful.

I'm unfortunately stumped on trying to extract some data from:

[http://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/artist/?query=%22faith%20no%20more%22][1]

I am looking to extract the id from the artist element, which should be b15ebd71-a252-417d-9e1c-3e6863da68f8. I can get this working in Base X with the following:

```
declare namespace mmd="http://musicbrainz.org/ns/mmd-2.0#";
```

declare variable $doc := doc("http://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/artist/?query=%22faith%20no%20more%22");
$doc/mmd:metadata/mmd:artist-list/mmd:artist/@id

However, in Google Sheets using Importxml, the best I can do is:

```
=IMPORTXML("http://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/artist/?query=%22faith%20no%20more%22","//@id")
```

This results in all 3 id results being returned:

b15ebd71-a252-417d-9e1c-3e6863da68f8
489ce91b-6658-3307-9877-795b68554c98
83f22bb6-4631-443c-bace-9fae8540362a

I am completely stumped and any help will be greatly appreciated.

Kind regards,

James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't been able to find any useful documentation on Google's IMPORTXML, but there is no evidence that it provides any way to establish a namespace binding, or that it supports the XPath 2.0 syntax `*:metadata` to select elements independent of namespace. If that's the case then you may need to resort to the horrible construct `*[local-name()='metadata']/*[local-name()='artist-list']/*[local-name()='artist']`

Comment: Thank you @MichaelKay. Just added  /@id at the end and works like a charm.

Comment: The "horrible construct" still works! Note there is no `/` or `//` at the beginning for this construct. Not an XPATH expert so would never have figured this out on my own.